# JQUERY -- Finding text wrapped in a SPAN, and outputting that to a <UL> as <LI>s

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a large body of text which has several sentences wrapped in yada

I'd like to find a way with JQUERY, to go through the entire body of text, and every time it find a span with class "findme", to take what ever copy is contianed between the tag and to append that to a UL as a LI

Ideas on how to do this efficiently?

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("span.findme").each(function() {
  $("<li>").text($(this).text()).appendTo("ul");
});
```